# Requesting data about user iOS

Tags: ios, swift, addressbookui

Is there an API in iOS which would allow me to discover information about the user who owns the phone?

The address book api would allow me access to their contacts, but how would I find out about the self user?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to know?  You could ask the user.  If you're just trying to prepopulate an account creation type thing you can usually get the info from a third party auth provider (facebook, twitter, etc).

Comment: I'm trying to pre populate data for them for a form, I have no problem asking consent -just want to make it easy for the users to register

Comment: I would suggest using third party auth as the easiest way to go.

Comment: Seems a little silly to go through a 3rd party to get the users details if the phone already knows them- TBH if apple is concerned with privacy, it'd help a app designer keep the data on the phone as much as possible.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go through all the contacts in the Address Book and see if any of them are marked with the owner flag.
**Edit**
This was removed a while back, another way is getting the device name
`UIDevice.currentDevice().name`
"Bob's Iphone"
Then you could cylce through the address book and find a bob, this is a solution i wouldn't recommend, the best bet might be to ask the user for their details

Comment: I haven't looked this up- what are the odds of them being flagged (is there always a owner?)

Comment: ah my bad, this got removed a while back

Answer (score 1):

Well there's not much more you can get from a user due to them wanting their privacy but there are a couple of things you can still find out about a user:

- [Get Device Info](https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit/blob/master/README.md) (find out more about their device)
- [HealthKit API](https://developer.apple.com/healthkit/) (Get users health data like how many steps they make what they eat and drink etc)
- Photo Album Access (access to their photos and videos)

That's about it really! Hope it helps :)

Comment: This would be with a users consent to access data- I just need basics like name, phone number, email address- nothing too crazy.

Comment: That's data you can't access without user input or permission.